# Unable to get access token with GoogleCredentials

Tags: google-api, google-oauth-java-client

I'm trying to get access token using my service account JSON file. However I'm unable to get access token.

```
GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream(serviceAccountJsonFile));
System.out.print(googleCredential.getAccessToken());
```

I get `null` every time.
I am able to use the same credentials with Python APIs.

Can someone point me if I'm missing something here.

Comment: I am facing the same problem did you get any success.

Comment: Yes. Got it working with the below code:

`GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream(serviceAccountJsonFile), 
GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance());`

Comment: I do not have the method `GetAccessToken()` in my `GoogleCredential` object. Mine is based on a Service Account. Any thoughts?

Comment: @FayazAhmed can you please add an answer with your method laid out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the below code:

```
GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream(serviceAccountJsonFile),  GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance());
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have resolved this myself by adding before the getToken the following command:

```
credential.refreshToken()
```

Your code would look like this:

```
GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream(serviceAccountJsonFile));
credential.refreshToken();
System.out.print(googleCredential.getAccessToken());
```

This is not properly documented in google's website but after adding it, this worked perfectly and the results are displayed with actual values.

Some other error I faced was the "com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(Ljava/io/InputStream;)J", in order to resolve it I had to correct the dependency I was using to this one:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
 <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
 <version>1.31.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Reference can be found [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/issues/1534)

I hope this helps you too mate!

Comment: GoogleCredential is depreciated. Can you provide example to get access token using GoogleCredentials? there's an 's' at the end now.